# Button Group Border Radius issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a button group that works for having multiple buttons inside it, or just one.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jssq20gn/

Here's the html:

```
<!--THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD WORK FOR WHEN THERE IS THREE BUTTONS-->
<article>
   <div class='btn-group'>
       <a class='button'>Test</a>
       <a class='button'>Test</a>
       <a class='button'>Test</a>
   </div>
</article>
<!--THIS WORKS TOO-->
<article>
   <div class='btn-group'>
       <a class='button'>Test</a>
       <a class='button'>Test</a>
   </div>
</article>
<!--THIS DOESN'T WORK, should have rounded borders-->
<article>
   <div class='btn-group'>
       <a class='button'>Test</a>
   </div>
</article>
```

It works for when there is more than one button, but when there is only one button, the button doesn't have rounded corners on all sides.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is `:last-child` is getting called after `:only-child`. And while this is an "only-child" it's also a "last-child" so the `:last-child` selector is overwriting the `only:child` in the CSS hierarchy. Move `:only-child` below `:last-child`:

```
.btn-group .button:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.btn-group .button:only-child {
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jssq20gn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

put the ".btn-group .button:only-child" as the last class in your css file

In your css both "last" and "only" modifies the same properties and to achieve the right layoyt the order in which they are specified is important.

http://jsfiddle.net/jssq20gn/1/

```
.btn-group .button {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.btn-group .button:first-child {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px;
}
.btn-group .button:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;
    margin-left: -1px;
}
.button {
    padding: 10px;
    background: teal;
    border: 1px Black solid;
    color: #FFF;
}
article {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.btn-group .button:only-child {
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```